# Archlinux pip and setuptools not upgraded

Tags: python, pip, archlinux

Terminal command :

```
python -V output: Python 3.5.2
```

I'm trying `pip` and `setuptools` update on `pycharm` but this error occurred :

> Error :python packaging tool 'pip' not found.

Proposed solution:

> Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python3.5'.

Terminal command :

```
which pip output: usr/bin/pip
```

And I'm trying on terminal command :

```
pacman -S(or -Syu,-Syy) python-pip or pacman -S(-Syu,-Syy) python-setuptools

resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) python-packaging-16.7-1 python-pyparsing-2.1.5-1
             python-setuptools-1:24.0.2-1 python-six-1.10.0-2
             python-pip-8.1.2-1

Total Installed Size: 8.03 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(5/5) checking keys in keyring              [######################] 100%
(5/5) checking package integrity            [######################] 100%
(5/5) loading package files                 [######################] 100%
(5/5) checking for file conflicts           [######################] 100%
error:failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python-setuptools: /usr/bin/easy_install exists in filesystem
python-setuptools: /usr/bin/easy_install-3.5 exists in filesystem
python-pip: /usr/bin/pip exists in filesystem
python-pip: /usr/bin/pip3 exists in filesystem
python-pip: /usr/bin/pip3.5 exists in filesystem
Errors occured, no packages were upgraded.
```

So I'm trying :

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Output :

> /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

How to update pip ?

Comment: As a matter of best practice it is always good to keep a line between packages managed by `pacman` and by `pip`.  The problem occurs because you installed a pipy pip over the pip managed by pacman.  For python i'd argue that `python` itself, `pip` and `virtualenv` shall be kept under `pacman`'s management whilst all other packages under `pip`'s.

Comment: @grochmal This really should be an answer, as you've provided a way to prevent such a situation --- and, yes, I did upgrade `pip` with `pip`.

Answer (score 9):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240252/pacman-exists-on-filesystem-error) should work:

```
pacman -S --force python-pip and pacman -S --force python-setuptools
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to install python packages along with pacman. because pacman doesn't recognize any package installed by pip. I think you should remove all pip packages instelled using pip and reinstall all python packages using pacman or virtualenv. if you need python packages for arch you can search through AUR or you can install any python packages in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most up-to-date version from `pypi` and not from repository, then do something like

```
pip install -U pip
```