# Unable to install ROS - error in python2 setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, ros, archlinux

I am running Antergos(arch based linux) an trying to install ROS kinetic using the command

```
yaourt ros-kinetic-ros-core
```

while installing it throughed error saying

```
(7/7) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                  [#############################################################################] 100%
(7/7) checking package integrity                                                                                                [#############################################################################] 100%
(7/7) loading package files                                                                                                     [#############################################################################] 100%
(7/7) checking for file conflicts                                                                                               [#############################################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python2-setuptools: /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_install.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_install.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/archive_util.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/archive_util.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/alias.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/alias.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_rpm.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_rpm.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_wininst.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_wininst.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_egg_info.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_egg_info.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/register.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/register.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/rotate.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/rotate.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/saveopts.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/saveopts.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/setopt.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/setopt.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/upload.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/upload.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/upload_docs.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/upload_docs.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/depends.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/depends.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/glob.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/glob.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/launch.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/launch.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/lib2to3_ex.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/lib2to3_ex.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/msvc.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/msvc.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/namespaces.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/namespaces.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py26compat.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py26compat.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py27compat.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py27compat.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py31compat.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py31compat.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script.tmpl exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/site-patch.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/site-patch.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/ssl_support.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/ssl_support.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/unicode_utils.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/unicode_utils.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py exists in filesystem
python2-setuptools: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.pyc exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

later i happend to find that my default version was changed and also was somehow directing to anacondas version.

```
➜  ~ which pip
/home/arvindh/.miniconda3/bin/pip
➜  ~ which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python2.7
➜  ~
```

i want to change this to the default version. need some help in fixing this up please.

Comment: What I did once I got this is to `rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/*` and reinstall ... For the version, you should fix alias under your `~/.bashrc` instead of the command ...

Comment: @funilrys , i removed all files under `setuptools/commands/` and reinstalled setuptools using this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286682/3869739). later the default verson was python3 and not 2. so i changed in my `.zshrc` file and bash as well. and tried to install `ros`, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move from yaourt to pacaur. 
Pacaur is recommended please take a look at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table) for more information.

`pacaur -S ros-kinetic-ros-core` should install all dependencies.

I took a look at the [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ros-kinetic-ros-core) and it seems like you need Python 2.7 to run it.

I suspect [those lines](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ros-kinetic-ros-core#n61) to be responsible for the changes from python3 to python2

```
# Fix Python2/Python3 conflicts
/usr/share/ros-build-tools/fix-python-scripts.sh -v 2 ${srcdir}/${_dir} with the following into the PKGBUILD
```

So you should install the python2 `pip` && `setuptools`:

```
pacman -S python2-pip python2-setuptools
```

## EDIT

According to [there](https://hastebin.com/vaxipugiqo.js) where you have such issues:

```
python2-argparse: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py exists in filesystem
python2-argparse: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_common.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_common.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_version.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_version.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/easter.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/easter.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/win.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/win.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tzwin.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tzwin.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/dateutil-zoneinfo.tar.gz exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.py exists in filesystem
python2-dateutil: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-docutils: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python2-docutils: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/__init__.pyc exists in filesystem
python2-docutils: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/_compat.py exists in filesystem
python2-docutils: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/_compat.pyc exists in filesystem
```

you should delete those file with

```
rm path/to/the/file
```

so with the following example you should execute

```
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_common.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_common.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_version.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/_version.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/easter.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/easter.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/__init__.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/win.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/win.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tzwin.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tzwin.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/dateutil-zoneinfo.tar.gz 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/__init__.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/__init__.pyc 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/_compat.py 
rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/_compat.pyc
```

### Back to your case

You should execute the list of commands [there](https://hastebin.com/yoyoganuro.php) (it's just an application of the example above but with the list of everything that should be deleted before reinstallation.)

Comment: i am getting multiple errors like `ERROR: pacman fails to install missing dependencies` and also `error: target not found: ros-.....`

Comment: @arvindh can you give us the full log output ?

Comment: im extremely sorry. the error message is extremely huge, and i dont know how to paste it in. can you please help me in telling, if is there any external site to post just the error message and sharing the link over here.

Comment: @arvindh Updated my answer :)

Comment: I tried to remove all conflicting files and folders and later i ecexuted the command to install ROS... then i ended up with different set of errors. As the outpot is extremely large and hastebin wasnt accepting it, i have slpit them up. [firstly](https://hastebin.com/juyejolape.coffeescript) and [then](https://hastebin.com/serohewaci.coffeescript)

Comment: you need to `rm /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_yaml.so` and I think that you missed an update of pacaur ... try `pacaur -Syyua` for  a full update of package from AUR or try `pacaur -S pacaur` for the update of pacaur before reinstalling :)

Comment: great,.. i tried to remove all the existing files and re-ran the command after doing the update what u hav mentopned. it wored ,. thanks a lot funilrys

Answer (score 0):

You can use home-brew: `brew install python`. It should give you the option to set as default when it finishes. If you want python 3 just do `brew install python3`.

Comment: sorry, if i am right, this is for Mac/OSX right. I am using Arch based linux

Comment: Yes. If you are not on a mac, you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679674/changing-default-python-to-another-version

Comment: tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679822/3869739. unable to install ros. still getting the same error

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `sudo rm /usr/bin/python`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: if you're trying to install a new version, try the `--ignore-installed` flag or `--force-reinstall`. (Do this with `pip install (package)`

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Thought you were trying to reinstall python

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have linux so run this command.

```
alias python=python3
```

Comment: alising is not the option i am looking for. Though, it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

That error is not related to ROS.

You probably tried to install locally with `pip` globally, that is why it says there are conflicting files.

Quick dirty guide to solve this kind of errors:

1. Force install: `pacman -S --force python2-setuptools`
2. Uninstall ignoring deps: `pacman -Rdd python2-setuptools`
3. Reinstall: `pacman -S python2-setuptools`

Hopefully this solves it.

Comment: tried ,.. im still getting the errors as mentioned in the comment for @funilrys answer